# How to calculate the time remaining to complete an operation?

Tags: c#

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't matter to what number I change the progressbar1.value is changed too, I still get the same result 0. I am guessing that the problem lies in the timespent Variable, but I can't figure it out.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            // run the process here
           Thread.Sleep(100);
            // end process
            sum = sum + i;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);



            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
        }
        // displays the sum of the process
        e.Result = sum;

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label5.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

        DateTime starttime = DateTime.Now;
        var timespent = DateTime.Now - starttime;
        double secondsremaining = (double)(timespent.TotalSeconds / progressBar1.Value) * (progressBar1.Maximum - progressBar1.Value);
        label7.Text = "Time remaining:" + (int)secondsremaining;
        Console.WriteLine(secondsremaining);

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            label5.Text = "Processing Cancelled";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            label5.Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "Sum = " + e.Result.ToString();
        }
        label6.Text = "";
    }

    private void button11_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Checks if the background worker is busy running operations
        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            //this method will start the excution of the opreation
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        }
        else
        {
           label6.Text = "The operation is being completed, please wait...";
        }

    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Hey Federico, thanks for your quick reply. I am trying to calculate the time remaining of an operation. In my code, the number 5 represents the value that has to be calculated and timespend represents the time that has passed. I am trying to accomplish this for a progress bar.

Comment: the resolution of DateTime.Now is in 10E-7 seconds (ticks), the code is executed in nanoseconds, therefore timespent is zero. Even if resolution is high enough, you multiply with (100-5)/5=19 and truncate to int. Unless at least 53 msec are pasted (19*0.053>=1) the result  is always zero. What's your goal?

Comment: What operation? Which progress bar? Your code currently does nothing (apart from printing 0, as per @Melissa comment).

Comment: Hey Melissa, my goal is to get to get the time remaining in seconds.

Comment: @TonyBatista You want to get something like "Remaining time: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1"?

Comment: Hey guys, I've posted my code.

Comment: Melissa, I want to get something like this Time Remaining: 01:02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is reasonably close, but you have a mistake: your `starttime` variable is a local variable, which you reset to the current time immediately before trying to use it to compute the elapsed time. Thus, the elapsed time is always zero, or very close to.

You should move the variable to be an instance field, so that it can persist between the progress updates:

```
DateTime starttime;

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(
    object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int sum = 0;

    // Using UtcNow will ensure the time calculation is correct even if
    // the work occurs during a daylight saving time change-over
    starttimme = DateTime.UtcNow;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        // run the process here
       Thread.Sleep(100);
        // end process
        sum = sum + i;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);

        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
            return;
        }
    }
    // displays the sum of the process
    e.Result = sum;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(
    object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    label5.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";

    var timespent = DateTime.UtcNow - starttime;

    // Casting to double here is superfluous. TotalSeconds is already a
    // double, and its presence in the expression results in the rest of
    // the values being promoted to double and the expression type being double.
    double secondsremaining =
        (double)(timespent.TotalSeconds / progressBar1.Value) *
        (progressBar1.Maximum - progressBar1.Value);
    label7.Text = "Time remaining:" + (int)secondsremaining;
    Console.WriteLine(secondsremaining);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter I concluded the same thing with Melissa's help and a little more research. I really appreciate your answer thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{            
  DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;

  /// do something here... that actually takes time
  Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

  /// next estimate update
  {
    double WorkDone = 0.10; // e.g. 10%... give some indication how much work has been done between 0 and 1

    TimeSpan TimeSpent = DateTime.Now - StartTime;
    TimeSpan TimeOverall = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long) (TimeSpent.Ticks / WorkDone));
    TimeSpan TimeRemaining = TimeOverall - TimeSpent;

    Console.WriteLine(TimeRemaining.TotalSeconds);
  }
}
```

The DateTime.Now resolution is in Ticks or 1E-7 seconds, if you request the time too often then no time has passed. For higher resolution you need performance counters that can measure CPU cycles.